# DOSGI Custom Provider Registration

Tags: java, cxf, dosgi

I am trying to run DOSGI in Apache Felix.
I use CXF 3.2.0 bundles and DOSGI 2.3.0

I can successfully register services but I can not register global custom providers for my resources.

I have a Resource defined in interface:

```
@Path("")
public interface IToDoResource {

@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
List<ToDo> getAllToDos();

@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
ToDo getToDoById(@PathParam("id") Long id);
...
}
```

Then implemented in:

```
@Component(//
    name = "My.ToDoRestService", //
    immediate = true, //
    property = //
    { //
        "service.exported.configs=org.apache.cxf.rs", //
        "service.exported.interfaces=*", //
         "org.apache.cxf.rs.address=/todos", //
    } //
)
public class ToDoResource implements IToDoResource {
....
}
```

I try to register Global custom Providers for my classes.
I can make it working with **"service.exported.intents"** property on the resource and **"IntentName"** on the provider for one provider.
However for this resource I want to register 4 providers:

- ToDo XML provider
- ToDo Json provider
- ArrayList XML provider
- ArrayList Json provider

Alternatively I can also implement **IntentsProvider** on the resource and it also works.

However following does not work and I get no provider registered for this type error in the logs:

```
@Component(//
    name = "My.ToDoJsonProvider", //
    immediate = true, //
    service = MessageBodyWriter.class, //
    property = {
        "service.exported.configs=org.apache.cxf.rs", //
        "org.apache.cxf.rs.provider=true", //
    } //
)
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ToDoJsonProvider implements MessageBodyWriter<ToDo> {
```

GET on localhost:8080/cxf/todos/1 returns empty document and on logs:

> JAXRSUtils:1834] No message body writer has been found for class my.todo.repository.api.ToDo, ContentType: application/xml

What do I miss here to register a custom provider globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like intents are only taken into account when they are directly named in the Resource properties.
**"service.exported.intents"** property must list all intents that can are required by the resource.

I could not find any documentation but the source code of the RsProvider and IntentManagerImpl classes helped to me.

RsProvider:
https://github.com/apache/cxf-dosgi/blob/master/provider-rs/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/dosgi/dsw/handlers/rest/RsProvider.java

IntentManagerImpl:
https://github.com/apache/cxf-dosgi/blob/master/common/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/dosgi/common/intent/impl/IntentManagerImpl.java